# SelectOneMenu resets after delay

Tags: primefaces, selectonemenu

`SelectOneMenu` resets to first menu option if it still has focus after a few sec delay.

An example can be found on PrimeFaces Showcase :

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml .

If you select any option for either of the 4 selects and wait a few seconds without doing anything else (ie clicking out of the SelectOneMenu), the value resets to the first option in the list.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: does not happen here...

Comment: So we tested this problem on my 2 co-workers computers and nothing changes for them, but on mine it happens in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. @Kukeltje

Comment: So you are going to add the IE tag here? And test if it happens to plain jsf to and then the primefaces tag? And then check if your browser sends a new request? And then check all your browser plugins and remove the question?

Comment: Why would I add the IE tag? @Kukeltje

Comment: Sorry, chrome and firefox to, since they play as much a role in this as primefaces